# Seven young people are traveling by train to an amusement park.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, permutations

a) On the outward journey, there are exactly seven seats left in a train car. In how many ways can the young people distribute themselves among the free seats?

b) In the park they get to the roller coaster, and for the next ride there is still one car with four seats free. How many possibilities are there for filling these four seats ?

c) Look at part b) from another point of view: It has to be determined which three young people cannot be on the first ride. How many such determinations are there?

d) On the return trip in the evening, there are exactly 16 free seats in a train car. In how many ways can the young people distribute themselves among the free seats?

---

a) Permutation without repetition is done with factorials. There are seven people, so $7! = 5040$

b) Permutation with not everyone involved is given by the formula: $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ In our case, $n = 7$ and $r = 4$, so we get $\frac{7!}{(7-4)!} = 7!/3! $ <strike>= 4! = 24</strike>  $= 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 840 $

c) **Very unsure about this one.**  <strike>The three people can be ordered in 3! = 6 different ways. So for each of the 4! = 24 different way the four people are ordered in the car, there are actually only 24 / 6 = 4 ways where the three people remaining are not the same, is this correct ?</strike>  $\frac{7!}{3!(7-3)!} = \frac{7!}{3!4!} = 35$

d) The first person can choose any of the 16 seats, the second person can choose any of 15 seats, the third can choose any of 14 seats, etc.  $16 \cdot 15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 = 16! / (16 - 7)! = 57657600$

---

We have no solutions to this exercise, could you give me your feedback, especially for c) ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: For (c) you seem to be being asked how many ways are there of choosing the $3$ individuals not riding (and may not care about the seating positions of the $4$ riding)

Comment: The most important point : 7! / 3! , until this , it was ok. But saying that 7!/3! is 4!, it is a very very very big mistake.  $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ is not $r!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(b)** Your formula is right, but the computation is not

You could also compute it as $7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4 = 840$

**(c)** You are just asked to compute which three are left out, thus $\binom73 = 35$

Answer (score 1):

c) asks how many choices of 3 out of 7  you have .  first step   you choose 1 out of seven so you have 7 possibilities, next step you choose from the 6 remaining and finally from the 5 remaining. so it is easy to multiply.

Comment: How many **choices** out of $7$ is not $7\cdot6\cdot5$, it is $^7C_3$.

Comment: what ist  73? maybe a different way to calculate 7*6*5?

Comment: Just $(7choose 3), \binom 73 = \frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$